# Need deployment strategy with auto-update on all users

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, installation

I need a deployment method that do following thing:

1. Auto-update, like click-once;
2. Install on all users, like Visual Studio Setup projects.
3. without admistratives privileges. (except the first times for the requirements)
4. Can install VB Powerpacks.

The problems is that I'm making a winforms program, that might need to be updated anytime, and that our computers are use by many users (our company run 24hours/days). And we don't want to update my program manually on our 80 computers, for each users!

Click-once could be great if we can do an install for all users (but yes, I already find that it's not possible).

I'M STUCK! Please help.

Comment: You may want to consider WiX  - http://wixtoolset.org/

Answer (score 1):

We use a system where the shortcut to launch our application actually launches an auto-updater.  The updater checks the server for any update dlls, and if it finds them, it copies them to the local machine.  After that (or if it didn't find any updates), it then launches the application.

This will only work if you have some way to force everyone to log out every now and then.  We get around that by having the application watch for a specific file to be updated (the exe itself), and alerting the user every 5 minutes until they relaunch.